# как формируются HTTP-заголовки при отправлении SOAP-запроса серверу на языке Java?

Tags: java, http, soap

Подскажите пожалуйста, как формируются HTTP-заголовки при отправлении SOAP-запроса серверу? Написать надо из кода Java.
И как редактировать их или отключить их формирование?

Comment: по разному, зависит от используемой библиотеки: axis, axis2, metro, cxf, jbossws. вообще soap протокол не зависит от заголовков, кроме тех, которые обеспечивают выполнение POST метода

Comment: мне и нужно методом POST отправить запрос.. Без помощи всяких библиотек

Comment: Без помощи библиотек. И что означает "протокол не зависит от заголовков?"

Comment: httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json")

Comment: свойство "application/json" это вы придумали, или реально существует?
Если я не указываю setRequestProperty то HTTPConnect по умолчанию будет добавлять?

Comment: возьмите программу SoapUI, при создании проекта по wsdl описанию, она вам создаст примеры запросов в виже xml, которые можно будет отправлять простым POST запросом, только параметры в xml вам нужно будет подставлять самому.